# How to disable button for showing history/currently running tasks in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to disable the button which is used for showing running/recent task in android for ICS or above devices programatically at the start of my application & re enable after exiting from my app so how it could be achieved?

Comment: You cannot do this and you should not. The button belongs to the Android system and is out of the scope of your Application.